# Warning: number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)

Tags: r

I am trying to split a column. my data frame (menuD) is like

```
Column1
1|3|4|5
4|5|6|7
```

I wanted to split the numbers in column1 so I did this.

```
menuD <- data.frame (do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(myCmenu$myFile.menudata), '|', fixed = TRUE)))
```

I got the expected result which is like this

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
  1  |  3   |  4   | 5
  4  |  5   |  6   | 7
```

But I got this warning message from R

```
> Warning message:
In rbind(c("", "164200", "", "167", "108", "112", "116", "120"),  :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

I'd like to know, did this effect my data? is all the data separated properly?

Comment: The example you give works for me?

Comment: The number of elements in the original dataset may not be the same for each row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the example provided, either `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(menuD, "Column1", "|")
#   Column1_1 Column1_2 Column1_3 Column1_4
#1:         1         3         4         5
#2:         4         5         6         7
```

---

Or `separate` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(menuD, Column1, into = paste0("col", 1:4))
```

---

Or  `read.table/read.csv` can be used.

```
read.table(text=menuD$Column1, sep="|", fill=TRUE, header=FALSE)
```

But, the warning in the OP's post indicates that there might be elements in the "Column1" with less number of `|`.  In that case, the `cSplit` or the last option should work.

Comment: Thanks for the edit akrun. I am trying the first option now. for the last option, will it change the data type of my data.frame?

Comment: @RayanSp If you have a factor column use `read.table(text=as.character(menuD$Column1), sep="|", fill=TRUE, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` can be used.  In the `cSplit`, there is an option to convert the class by default.

Comment: read.table is absolutely slow, its still running (the previous method I tried took seconds) is that normal?

Comment: @RayanSp Try with `fread` if `read.table` is slow i.e. `library(data.table);fread(paste(menuD$Column1, collapse="\n"))`